# Prevent jquery from being referenced more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there something I can wrap around the body of my jquery include file to prevent it from being included twice?  My problem is that my application has multiple includes and I want to prevent jquery from being referenced in multiple includes and breaking.

My thoughts would be to open my jquery file (jquery-1.4.2.js) and put some sort of logic around the entire block of jquery library code.

Something like:

> if (jQueryIsAlreadyIncluded()) 
>   { //jquery library code
>   {(function(A,w){function ma(){if(!c.......
>
> }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
   //jquery library code {(function(A,w){function ma(){if(!c.......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmmm
Boilerplate does this when using the googleapi jquery, so you could use it for local files too

```
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="yourpathtojquery"><\/script>')</script>
```

This is only for jquery itself though, otherwise you could set some variables and then in each library check if the variable is set, if not include, else exclude.....

```
if(!($Mylib))
{
    //Your javascript here....

    Mylib = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
if (typeof jQuery === undefined) {

    // jQuery code

}
```

Comment: This will throw an error (`jQuery is not defined`). You should check for `typeof`